# Access variables stored in Wordpress Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

Within my Wordpress plugin, I am storing some variables:

```
        $results = get_aws_details($reg, $asin);
        $price = $results[0][0];               
        $url = $results[1][0];
        $wishlist = $results[2][0];
```

Essentially, my plugin is grabbing a field from each post, and returning the Amazon data on it, which is then being stored in the variables above.

What I need to do though is access these variables in my loop on the theme.
I've had everything working when it was hardcoded into the theme, but now I do not know how to access these variables.

Simply trying to add echo $price in my loop doesn't work

Any suggestions?  I know I could use global variables, but this isn't ideal

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom WordPress hook. Here is an example:

```
<?php
// loop
while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
   <div>
       <?= apply_filters("get_my_price"); ?>
   </div>
<?php endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

In your plugin now:

```
<?php
// plugin
$results = get_aws_details($reg, $asin);
$price = $results[0][0];
add_filter("get_my_price", function() use ($price) {
    return $price;
});
```

NOTE: The style of coding can change to however you want it to be. I just wanted to demonstrate how you can accomplish what you want without using global state. You'll also need to add a filter for the rest of your data. Alternatively you can use 1 filter then use a switch to match the data you want.

```
<?php
// theme
echo apply_filters("get_result", "price");

// plugin
$results = get_aws_details($reg, $asin);
add_filter("get_result", function($type) use($results) {
    switch ($type) {
        case "price":
             return $results[0][0];
    }
});
```